# Spark Architecture Basics

Tags: apache-spark, databricks

I have a basic question undertanding Spark Architecture.

In databricks community edition I can create a cluster with 2 cores .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SgA7.png)

As I have understood each core can create one task nothing but a partition.

I tried to create a sample rdd

rdd_first=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(15),6)

and I have seen it created 6 tasks .

Now I have a confusion how 2 cores cluster can create 6 tasks.

Can someone help me on this

I am expecting a to know if task and partition are same and relation between core and  task and partition

Answer (score 0):

In Databricks Community edition, since there is only a single node, it does a thread based parallelism. You will get the number of worker threads using the property ***spark.sparkContext.master***. In your case that is set by default(since a spark session is created for you), and you can retrieve this config and see the value for yourself.

You could also check the timing of the job in the Spark UI, and see when the tasks were added and removed.
Apart from that , every core operates on a single task and every task on a single partition. And yes, cores can be reused to perform other tasks too.

Comment: Okay , So I understand that since it is a single node , it will operate the parallelism in the thread level and let's say for example , each core has a single thread and 2 partitions can run in parallel at a time and once they are done these cores will be reused to get another partitions and perform transformations.   Thank you !!